# Are haskell list comprehensions lazy?

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation, idioms, ghci

After a long while dealing with other languages, I wanted to refresh my aging Haskell skills a little with some codegolf inspired computation (which is intended to be lengthy). In the code below, I relied on lazy computation - but instead of a result, the machine ran out of memory...

```
import Data.Word

kernel :: (Word32,Word32) -> Word32
kernel (i,j) = div (i*j) 3

result :: Word32
result = sum (fmap kernel
              [(i,j) |
               i <- [0 :: Word32 .. 10000],
               j <- [0 :: Word32 .. 10000]])
```

So my questions are:

- Is the list comprehension here not supposed to be lazy and then lazily provide data to `fmap` and eventually `sum`?
- How else would I do it idiomatically? (I know, I could do a tail recursion implementation but that appears a bit too low level here).

Comment: In a way, yes. I will check, if the compiled version behaves the same as if I `:load` the source into ghci.

Comment: The better solution is to use `foldl'` instead of `sum`.

Comment: the `foldl'` version of the above code works also in ghci. But the result value is not as expected. It is supposed to produce the same output as the c++ code: `extern "C" uint32_t c_result() {
  uint32_t s,i,j;
  for (s = UINT32_C(0), i = UINT32_C(0); i < UINT32_C(10000);i++) {
    for (j = UINT32_C(0); j < UINT32_C(10000); j++) {
      s += (i*j) / UINT32_C(3);
    }
  }
  return s;
}`

Comment: Haskell ranges are inclusive.

Comment: Could not reproduce. After adding `main = print result`, and compiling with `ghc -O2`, I get a program that runs in 0.9s and uses 9MB max residency. (And, btw, code review: `sum [div (i*j) 3 | ...]` would be more idiomatic.)

Comment: @interjay GHC is smart enough to `foldl'` when you write `sum`. You just have to tell it you want it to be smart... by compiling with `-O2`.

Comment: @DanielWagner If a program eats all your memory and crashes when you run without optimizations (or in the interpreter), I consider that a bug.

Comment: @interjay I mainly fell into that trap because currently I mostly do Common Lisp with SBCL, which ALWAYs compiles (and optimizes) in the repl if I reload a source file.